# Копирование файла на сервер Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor

Всем привет.

Я хотел реализовать сохранение файла на сервере. По теме нашёл это видео: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZKzl2THT5zg и в принципе всё получилось. Но есть одно весомое "но": при такой реализации требуется очень много оперативной памяти. Вот предложенный автором метод сохранения файла:

```
public async Task upload(IFileListEntry file)
    {
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        var path = Path.Combine(webHostEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "UploadedFiles", DateTime.Today.ToString("dd_MM_yyyy") + "_" + file.Name);


        await file.Data.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);

        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)) {
            memoryStream.WriteTo(fileStream);
        }
    }
```

Вот что происходит если вкинуть файл на 80 мб:

[image: Вот что происходит если вкинуть файл на 80 мб]

Сперва я подумал что проблема в memoryStream:

1)

```
// пробовал использовать memoryStream внутри usnig, чтобы освобождать после использования всю память 
// им занятую
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream()){
            var path = Path.Combine(webHostEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "UploadedFiles", DateTime.Today.ToString("dd_MM_yyyy") + "_" + file.Name);

            await file.Data.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);

            using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)) {
                memoryStream.WriteTo(fileStream);
            }
        }
```

2. 

```
// пробовал очищать memoryStream после
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        var path = Path.Combine(webHostEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "UploadedFiles", DateTime.Today.ToString("dd_MM_yyyy") + "_" + file.Name);

        await file.Data.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);

        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)) {
            memoryStream.WriteTo(fileStream);
        }

        memoryStream.Close();
        memoryStream.Dispose();
```

Результат нулевой. Как забирает память, так не отдаёт обратно.
Возможно другой метод копирования на подобии [такого](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31821880/how-to-create-copy-of-file-using-streamreader-and-streamwriter) дал бы мне лучший результат:

```
private void copyStream(Stream src, Stream dest)
    {
        int _bufferSize = 1024;
        var buffer = new byte[_bufferSize];
        int len;
        while ((len = src.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            dest.Write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
    }
```

Но я не понимаю как мне воспользоваться в данной ситуации таким алгоритмом. Я попросту не могу понять как мне преобразовать IFileListEntry в Stream чтобы его можно было скормить данной функции.

В самом Blazor я использую библиотеку "BlazorInputFile".

Помогите пожалуйста либо применить копирование с использованием буфера, либо скажите в чём проблема в методе upload.

Comment: GC отдаст память тогда, когда посчитает нужным. Вам не надо об этом беспокоиться, если у вас явно нет утечек памяти.

Comment: Вы гадаете, есть ли утечка, если есть то где она. Если не уверены - возьмите профилировщик в руки, сделайте снэпшот и проанализируйте.

Comment: Ну вы можете для очистки совести попробовать вызывать `GC` вручную после окончания блока `using`, чтобы убедиться, что память таки будет отдаваться обратно, когда у `GC` до неё руки дойдут.

Comment: @CrazyElf отдаёт, но не много. Явно меньше чем приложению надо чтобы просто работать.
Без этого всего оно ест 150 мб памяти. А после копирования доходит до 500. Ума не приложу что я мог сделать настолько неправильно.

Comment: @Evgeniy `GC.Collect()` вызывали после окончания блока `using`? Память проверяли через `GC.GetTotalMemory(true))`? Просто без явной сборки мусора C# будет держать занятую память пока процент свободной памяти не упадёт ниже определённого порога и только тогда автоматически вызовется `GC`. Это нормальная стратегия в общем случае.

Comment: Напомните, кто лучше знает: LOH же вроде как только растёт и не уменьшается, верно? Не смотрел, как реализована загрузка больших файлов, может просто весь файл целиком попадает в кучу больших объектов и потом топикстартеру не нравится, что не получает обратно занятое?

Comment: @CrazyElf да, именно после закрытия using вызвал GC.Collect(), он освободил 200 мб. Но странно что не больше. Через GC.GetTotalMemory(true)) смотрю, и только меньше понимаю чему верить.

Comment: Выкидываем MemoryStream. Открываем FileStream. Потом вызываем `...CopyToAsync(fiileStream)`

Comment: Вклинюсь в беседу. Large Object Heap можно [компактировать](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.gcsettings.largeobjectheapcompactionmode?view=net-5.0)

Comment: Вот что ещё могу предложить: [RecyclableMemoryStream](https://github.com/microsoft/Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream). Если в приложении действительно активно используются MemoryStream'ы, то есть смысл заюзать. Но в данном конкретном случае это вряд ли необходимо.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov спасибо большое. Действительно гораздо бережнее с памятью обращается такой алгоритм.

var path = Path.Combine(webHostEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "UploadedFiles", "_" + DateTime.Today.ToString("dd_MM_yyyy") + "_" + file.Name);
using (FileStream outFileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                await file.Data.CopyToAsync(outFileStream);
            }

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Нет. Не особо активно. Даже больших файлов не планируется, только Word/Excel документы. Думаю с ними не так полохо будет, как с большими файлами. Просто хотелось понять куда девается память.

Comment: Видимо натурально у вас из-за MemoryStream LOH росла и фрагментировалась